# excel js add-in manifest requirements section

Tags: excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

we have excel js add with custom function support and because of it, this add-in works just in excel office 365 version.
here we met a problem - "npm validate" define this add-in as an add-in for excel 2016, but that is not correct for us.
so the question is - how to correctly set the "requirements" section in the manifest file to define this add-in as an add-in for office 365?

currently, it looks like

```
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Functions use separate requirement sets from the core Excel JavaScript APIs. You could refer to this page for Custom Functions requirement sets:
[Custom Functions requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-requirement-sets)

Comment: sorry but I don't really understand what do you want to say. as you can see above I have this statement in my requirements section.